# How to write a login function in luminus or use friend?

Tags: clojure

I am beginning to use luminus framework to develop a web app, and I am trying to use friend for auth, I am stacked here, I don't know how to use that like using gem in rails app.
I don't know where should I put the code in luminus, is there anyone can show me a demo. Or tell me what to do next?
Well, you can also tell me how to write a log in function in luminus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from when I did a luminus+friend combination, granted, they've changed the template several times, so this is from an older version, but the concepts the same, I hope it helps.

```
(def all-routes
  [home-routes cljs-routes test-routes app-routes])

(def app
  (-> all-routes middleware/app-handler ))

(def secured-app
  (handler/site
  (friend/authenticate app{
                         :login-uri "/login"
                         :unauthorized-redirect-uri "/login"
                         :credential-fn (partial creds/bcrypt-credential-fn users)
                         :workflows [(workflows/interactive-form)]})))

(def war-handler
  (middleware/war-handler secured-app))
```

Answer (score 2):

The login sort of works like it is posted in the [Luminus Docs](http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/sessions_cookies.md). Not sure if you managed to read that part, but I'll show you a simplified version of the code I use. I want to mention that I removed quite a bit of code to make everything a bit easier to understand, so this may not work as-is since I only deleted code and extra parens. Since it is from actual working code, it will work with a bit of tweeking:

The first part is getting the login form:

```
(defn login-page []
  (html5
    [:h3 "Login"]
    [:form {:method "POST" :action "login"}
     [:div "Username:" 
      [:input {:type "text" :name "username" :required "required"}]]
    [:div "Password:"
     [:input {:type "password" :name "password" :required "required"}]]
    [:div 
     [:input {:type "submit" :value "Log In"}]]]]))
```

Notice that there is a "POST" method? In order to get the routes to work, you have to have a "POST" route, but you will also need a "GET" route. This is the simplified version of the "GET" "POST" loop that I have:

```
(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/login" []
       (log/login-page))

  (POST "/login" [username password]
        (do-login username password)))
```

The (do-login) function is where I authenticate the user / password combo, which then sets the session, which is shown downn below.

Notice that the POST route needs arguments. The arguments must match the "name" parameters in the form.

Finally, to get it all to work, you have to hook up some sessions. I personally use lib-noir.sessions:

```
(ns myapp.handler
  (:require [noir.session :as sesh])
```

Then you have to create a map to hold the session, which I'm wrapping in a function here (note that the :key *must* match whatever you have in your database:

```
(defn set-user [username]
  (sesh/put! :handle username))
```

And finally, you have to tell clojure that you want to allow sessions to be handled via middleware:

```
(def app
  (sesh/wrap-noir-session
    (handler/site
     app-routes)))
```

Hopefully that gives you a bit of a headstart. I did not include how to connect to a database or how to use a map, but the above should be enough to get you on your way. I also did not touch on authorization and security (please don't skip this!). Using a database, map, or friend isn't a huge quantum leap from here. Just wanted to offer just enough to get you started.

Comment: Well, that is helpful I think, I can write that in java way, or ruby way, I just don't the codes in the framework how to interact with each other.

Comment: All I can say is don't over-think it.

Comment: And can you give some demo to see the exactly code? I am okay with your part about render a form and I am confused with session part. I just dont understand. Is that necessary to handle session by middleware?

Comment: That code is working code. You can essentially copy / paste the code and use a map like you'd see in the friend demos http://friend-demo.herokuapp.com/. Yes, the middleware is mandatory.